# What Cases Require Synchronized Method Access in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, methods, non-static

In what cases is it necessary to synchronize access to instance members? 
I understand that access to static members of a class always needs to be synchronized- because they are shared across all object instances of the class.

My question is when would I be incorrect if I do not synchronize instance members?

for example if my class is

```
public class MyClass {
    private int instanceVar = 0;

    public setInstanceVar()
    {
        instanceVar++;
    }

    public getInstanceVar()
    {
        return instanceVar;
    }
}
```

in what cases (of usage of the class `MyClass`) would I *need* to have methods:
`public synchronized setInstanceVar()` and
`public synchronized getInstanceVar()` ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It depends on whether you want your class to be thread-safe. Most classes shouldn't be thread-safe (for simplicity) in which case you don't need synchronization. If you need it to be thread-safe, you should synchronize access *or* make the variable volatile. (It avoids other threads getting "stale" data.)

Answer (score 40):

The `synchronized` modifier is really a *bad* idea and should be avoided at all costs.  I think it is commendable that Sun tried to make locking a little easier to acheive, but `synchronized` just causes more trouble than it is worth.

The issue is that a `synchronized` method is actually just syntax sugar for getting the lock on `this` and holding it for the duration of the method.  Thus, `public synchronized void setInstanceVar()` would be equivalent to something like this:

```
public void setInstanceVar() {
    synchronized(this) {
        instanceVar++;
    }
}
```

This is bad for two reasons:

- All `synchronized` methods within the same class use the exact same lock, which reduces throughput
- Anyone can get access to the lock, including members of other classes.

There is nothing to prevent me from doing something like this in another class:

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();
synchronized(c) {
    ...
}
```

Within that `synchronized` block, I am holding the lock which is required by all `synchronized` methods within `MyClass`.  This further reduces throughput and *dramatically* increases the chances of a deadlock.

A better approach is to have a dedicated `lock` object and to use the `synchronized(...)` block directly:

```
public class MyClass {
    private int instanceVar;
    private final Object lock = new Object();     // must be final!

    public void setInstanceVar() {
        synchronized(lock) {
            instanceVar++;
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `java.util.concurrent.Lock` interface and the `java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock` implementation to achieve basically the same result (in fact, it is the same on Java 6).

Comment: @Daniel I liked your explanation a lot but shouldn't it 'must' be declared 'static' as well especially to have Thread-safe public classes ? As you also want to guaranty that all threads for attaining lock will use same (shared) object that doesn't get modified. `private static final Object lock = new Object(); // must be static final`

Comment: There is no need for `lock` to be `static` since the data it is synchronizing (`instanceVar`) is itself not-static.  Static locks are almost always a sign of very, very serious trouble and you should avoid them whenever possible.

Comment: @Daniel hmmm... I guess I missed the point that here 'MyClass' doesn't extends Thread so it won't be having it's own threads. So here the purpose of making the class thread safe is that when some external threads are sharing same object (instance) of 'MyClass' then they should access [update] the instanceVar in a synchronized manner. In other words the lock should have been declared 'static' if MyClass was declared extending Thread. Right?

Comment: Extending `Thread` is really just an implementation detail.  It's bad practice, btw, but still doable.  If you do that, then you will have *at least* two threads running against the same instance.  Those threads would use the exact same lock object.  However, for threads running against different instances of `MyClass`, there's no point in locking on the same object because they're not accessing the same data!  So, we could make it static, but there's absolutely no benefit and a lot of pain if we do.

Comment: @Daniel aren't you missing the case when MyClass is a Thread (i.e. extends Thread -or- implements runnable) and has a static field that all threads, running against different instances, are trying to access (update) it via calling non-static method then wouldn't we require to take a lock over `private static final Object = new Object()`. However, if the method which updates the static field is itself static then we can achieve the same synchronization by simply declaring the method as synchronized.

Comment: Concurrent access to a static mutable variable is not only bad practice, it's actively suicidal.  However, if we were to do it, then yes, the `lock` would need to be static and use of the `synchronized` modifier would be acceptable (though still not preferable).

Comment: Nice explanation but can you explain why "must be final!"?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make this class thread safe I would declare `instanceVar` as `volatile` to make sure you get always the most updated value from memory and also I would make the `setInstanceVar()` `synchronized` because in the JVM an increment is not an atomic operation.

```
private volatile int instanceVar =0;

public synchronized setInstanceVar() { instanceVar++;

}
```

Comment: No need to make the field volatile, but setInstanceVar() does need to be synchronized.

Comment: Or you can use a java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger.

Comment: Daniel: If the getInstanceVar is not synchronized then the volatile makes sure that the value returned is fresh. But that's probably going to be lost on most programmers.

Comment: InverseFalcon: AtomicInteger may cause problems if there are large numbers of these objects. AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater may be better, but tends to give significantly worse performance when you have to use it.

Comment: @Tom, wouldn't you want your get method to be synchronized as well?

Answer (score 1):

. Roughly, the answer is "it depends". Synchronizing your setter and getter here would only have the intended purpose of guaranteeing that multiple threads couldn't read variables between each others increment operations:

```
 synchronized increment()
 { 
       i++
 }

 synchronized get()
 {
   return i;
  }
```

but that wouldn't really even work here, because to insure that your caller thread got the same value it incremented, you'd have to guarantee that you're atomically incrementing and then retrieving, which you're not doing here - i.e you'd have to do something like

```
  synchronized int {
    increment
    return get()
  }
```

Basically, synchronization is usefull for defining which operations need to be guaranteed to run threadsafe (inotherwords, you can't create a situation where a separate thread undermines your operation and makes your class behave illogically, or undermines what you expect the state of the data to be). It's actually a bigger topic than can be addressed here.

This book  [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) is excellent, and certainly much more reliable than me.

Answer (score 1):

To simply put it, you use synchronized when you have mutliple threads accessing the same method of the same instance which will change the state of the object/or application.

It is meant as a simple way to prevent race conditions between threads, and really you should only use it when you are planning on having concurrent threads accessing the same instance, such as a global object.

Now when you are reading the state of an instance of a object with concurrent threads, you may want to look into the the java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock -- which in theory allows many  threads to read at a time,  but only one thread is allowed to write.  So in the getter and setting method example that everyone seems to be giving, you could do the following:

```
public class MyClass{
    private ReentrantReadWriteLock rwl = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    private int myValue = 0;

    public void setValue(){
        rwl.writeLock().lock();
        myValue++;
       rwl.writeLock().unlock();
    }

    public int getValue(){
       rwl.readLock.lock();
       int result = myValue;
       rwl.readLock.unlock();
       return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with ReadWriteLock is it imposes some extra overhead.  This overhead is only worthwhile if you have *long* read operations, otherwise you're better off with just a single ReentrantLock.

Answer (score -3):

In Java, operations on ints are atomic so no, in this case you don't need to synchronize if all you're doing is 1 write and 1 read at a time.

If these were longs or doubles, you do need to synchronize because it's possible for part of the long/double to be updated, then have another thread read, then finally the other part of the long/double updated.

Comment: Though be careful of the ++ and -- operators, they're not atomic.  To be on the safe side, try using classes from java.util.concurrent.atomic.

Comment: Operations on integers aren't atomic in Java.

Comment: You can modify an int from different threads, get localized caching in the threads, have the ++ operation read and write out of sync. Just because longs and doubles read and write as two op operations (load upper and load lower to get all 64 bits) doesn't mean that integers suddenly become atomic because they suffer from 1 fewer non-threadsafe issues.